# Blended surface

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Partially blended surfaces are extensively used in the literature for shape preserving interpolation. Most of these shape preserving partially blended surface interpolation is based on the result that "shape-preserving
properties on the transfinite interpolating surface follows from shape-preserving properties of the network of boundary curves" which is claimed to be trivial (see, for instance, *Rational Interpolants with Tension Parameters* by Giulio Casciola and Lucia Romani [[PDF Link](http://www.dm.unibo.it/~casciola/html/papers/casciola02.pdf)]).

I do not find this to be trivial. Can anyone shed some light?